# javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory not working with ClassGuard

Tags: java, jpa, obfuscation

I just take a look at [ClassGuard](http://www.jsecurity.net/classguard/) (although I know some [objection](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html?page=2) to it).

However I get a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPU] class or package not found` that I do not get without ClassGuard.

The Exception is caused by a *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException* when my `@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "MyPU")` annotated class is not found.

ClassGuard overrides the class loader to load encrypted class files. Hence this may be a problem.

*Can I even use ClassGuard together with JPA?*

Unfortunately I could not find any related information or mailing lists on the web. And since ClassGuard was recommended here on SO a few times, I thought I give it a try...

Thanks
Mike

Comment: A total guess, but I'm hoping it might help, the guys in this thread seem to have the same problem as you do. http://seamframework.org/Community/GenerateuiThrowsClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

classguard does not have the problem you have mentioned in "objection" link since the encryption is in native code. Only way to hack is through native debugger. But with good licensing solution built around them and layering the distributable in such a way that core business logic resides in server library, it should not be too much of an issue I guess.

Hope you are setting the JVM arg to use ClassGuard classloader.
java ........ -Djava.system.class.loader=net.jsecurity.classguard.bootstrap.ClassGuard .......

However, if you use heavy reflection and mix up encrypted & un-crypted classes you might end up in trouble which I am currently sorting out with them.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what it did in the end. (Spoiler: Not a solution more a work around.)

I factored out the persistence stuff into another .jar file and had ClassGuard just not scramble it. Worked pretty well.